# how to maintain dropdownlist selected item after click of a button on the same page

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

im using an update panel whose update mode is set to conditional. i want to maintain the drop down list selection after I click a button which displays a form to enter information that pertains to that particular selected dropdownlist selection. how can this be done? i enabled view state of the dropdownlist itself to be tru but it isnt working... the list value always goes back to the original default value - 0

```
       <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListTug" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceTugs"
                                            DataTextField="Tug_Name" DataValueField="Tug_ID" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
                                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ShowNewRateBtn">
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="&lt;Select&gt;" Enabled="True" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                        <asp:Button ID="NewTug" runat="server" Text="New Tug" OnClick="NewTug_Click" 
                                            CausesValidation="False" Width="74px" />
                                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceTugs" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ g %>"
                                                                                              SelectCommand="SELECT [Tug_Name], [Tug_ID] FROM [COMIS_tbl_TugMaster]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

protected void ShowNewRateBtn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BtnNewRate.Visible = true;
    }
protected void BtnNewRate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

                processTugs.Visible = true;

                allButtons.Visible = true;

                BtnSave.Visible = true;

                BtnCancel.Visible = true;
              //  DropDownListTug.Focus();
              //  DropDownListTug.EnableViewState = true;
              //  DropDownListTug.SelectedValue = Session.... ;
           // }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
        }

    }enter code here
```

Comment: Please upload the code so that we can replicate the issue.

Comment: the only thing i have in the Page_Load is DropDownListTug.Enabled =true;

Comment: The relevant part is what is happening inside ShowNewRateBtn. I have deleted my answer because I have had an extremely long day with askers not providing enough information (and is really, really difficult and tiring to help anyone under these conditions).

Comment: thanks for the advice. i updated my ans anyway. hopefully someone else helps.

Comment: @New2This **I tested the about code, and it is working fine.** You want to create a new aspx page without master page, and copy the above code. Then debug it.

Comment: @New2This Please Post your full code .

Comment: @SurajSingh already posted^^^^

Comment: Check if page.ispostback and handle it depening on true /false

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="&lt;Select&gt;" Enabled="True" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
```

If you see this line in your `GridView` code i think you are providing a default value to your dropdown everytime it binds .

Your selection will be lost because of this attribute :-

`Selected="True"`

Comment: i changed it to false and its still not keeping the selection

Comment: @New2This Can you check your `DropDownListTug.SelectedValue` in `Page_Load` event is it's not null ?

Comment: @New2This Also check if your page is causing `PostBack` more than once for `BtnNewRate_Click` event , Put a debugger at `Page_Load`.

Answer (score 0):

i made a silly mistake quite really.. in my Cancel function which i called in the New Rate function,  i cleared the selection in there. removed it and its working fine now... thanks alot